# How to design databse for storing object states in mysql?

Tags: mysql-5.5, schema, table

I have multiple objects with multiple states. I want to build a timeline for each object. For example: an object might have a created, submitted, processing and success state. I would like to store when the object's state changes. I have 2 different solution in mind.

1. For each object model add columns with `[status]_at` name. In the above case the model will have `created_at`, `submitted_at`, `processing_at`, `success_at` columns.
2. Store the current object state in the object model. Create a separate table which stores the object state with time. In this case even if I want to add more states to objects it will not change my db schema.

What is the best way of storing the data? What are the pros and cons of the above solutions? Open for other solutions also.

Comment: Do You need to store states only or You need to store their timestamps too? In the first case You can add one field with `SET` data type and `created_at`, `submitted_at`, `processing_at`, `success_at` values list. In the second case I think Your technique 1 is the best way.

Comment: Is there a well defined series of transitions in your system?

Comment: @Akina I want to store both state and timestamp.  If i use `SET` data type will it make the update difficult?

Comment: @Vérace yes there will be defined series of transitions.

Comment: @AnandHegde *I want to store both state and timestamp.* If so, as written above, *I think Your technique 1 is the best way.* The data type of fields added will be TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL, and NOT NULL value means this state was reached.

Comment: @akina why not use 2nd approach, this makes it more generic right? In future if I want to add one more state to object it will be easier.

Comment: To obtain full history of all/most objects using 2nd approach You may use 4 LEFT-joined copies of state table. I think it is to degrade the performance. The only profit of that approach I see is insignificant disk space saving. Of course, if the most part of queries is "Find objects (in | reached | not reached) some state", the approach in question seems to be safe.

Comment: I'd refine your 2nd model to have a table for the objects and states each and an "object got state" table with FKs to objects and states and the time stamp. If I wanted a new state, fine, just an insert in the states table. If I wanted to allow cycles in the state changes one day, fine, just some inserts in the "object got state" table and I still keep the full history. On the other hand enforcing, that one state can only follow another is much easier in your first model. A check constraint, comparing the time stamps, would do. The other model would require triggers for that I suppose.